# Read the latest line from a file which keeps getting updated

Tags: python-3.x, file, logging

I currently coding a discord bot which reads a local log file which keeps getting updated. Every time a new line is added and matches a certain pattern the bot (should) post a messages with that content. I tried the following or my current stand is the following code. The current problem with my code is that the file is opened all the time. Is there a way to just read the file if its gets updated since the last reading? or in other words is there a way to realize my solution with a solution which does not need to have the file opened at all times/beeing busy with reading the file consitantly?

```
while not BOT.is_closed():        
    for log in logs:
        file_path = config["path_to_log"]
        logfiles= []
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,f'_{log}*')):
            logfiles.append(filename)
        latest_file = max(logfiles, key=os.path.getmtime)
        """ #second try doenst work if to much content gets added at the same time
        with open(latest_file,"rb") as f:
            if(len(messagelist)>1000):
                messagelist = []
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
            while f.read(1) != b'\n':
                f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
            last_line = f.readline().decode()
            for word in words:
                if word in last_line and last_line not in messagelist:
                    messagelist.append(last_line)
                    print(last_line)
                    await channel.send(last_line)
                else: 
                    time.sleep(1)
            """ 
        # first try it works but i dont think its the best solution
        try: 
            fp = open(latest_file, 'r')
        except:
            end_program("Error while reading the log file")

        for line in (fp.readlines() [-10:]): 
            new = line
            for word in words:
                if word in new and new not in messagelist:
                    messagelist.append(new)
                    print(new)
                    await channel.send(new)
                else: 
                    time.sleep(1)
                ###
        fp.close()
```

Comment: https://github.com/kasun/python-tail may help too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator.

```py
import time, os
def follow(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            if line.startswith('a'):
                yield line
```

The generator above will `yield` the lines with a newline character left at the end. You may want to slightly modify `yield line` to exclude the newline character, say, `yield line[:-1]`. `line.startswith('a')` is just an example to show how to `yield` lines that match a pattern. You will need to update this with your pattern.

In your code, you could use the generator as:

```py
for line in follow('/path/to/file'):
    # do something with line
```